# The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, postman, laravel-passport

I am developing an auth api with laravel, passport and postman. I have seen related post but none of them solved my problem. If I try to send a request it shows me this error. I have tried all I can but it just displays this error

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"message": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.",
"hint": "Check the `username` parameter"
}
```

my value for the application is

```
{
"grant_type" : "password",
"client_id" : "2",
"client_secret" : "fsDFrzGtmpMjoxWtplnvcmgKT3USzKFfKQu6alGF",
"email":"john@gmail.com",
"pssword" : "12345",
"scope" : "*"
}
```

api.php

```
<?php
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
Route::post('signup', 'SignUp@signUp');
```

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
  {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','vCode',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

  class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```

Please any solution will be really appreciated

Comment: You're getting the hint `"Check the username parameter"`, but I don't see `username` anywhere in your posted code; should `email` be replaced by `username` in your payload data perhaps? Also, you have `pssword`, which is a typo for `password`.

Comment: thanks i used email instead username

Comment: Where have you told passport that you want to use `email` and not `username` ?  Passport uses email address but OAUTH uses username   

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#password-grant-tokens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you required 'username' field and passing value in postman parameter 
After all your code is absolutly right.nothing error.

Comment: Yeah, I replaced the `email`  parameter to `username`  in postman and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `refresh_token` parameter

```
{
  "grant_type" : "password",
  "refresh_token" : 'your_refresh_token',
  "client_id" : "2",
  "client_secret" : "fsDFrzGtmpMjoxWtplnvcmgKT3USzKFfKQu6alGF",
  "email":"john@gmail.com",
  "pssword" : "12345",
  "scope" : "*"
}
```

See the documentation for more information : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#refreshing-tokens